# Combine multiple files into single file in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I want to combine the data of 3 (say) files having the same columns and datatype for those, into a single file, which I can further use for processing.
Currently I have to process the files one after the other. So, I am looking for a solution which I can write in a script to combine all the files into one single file.
For ex:
File 1:

```
mike,sweden,2015
tom,USA,1522
raj,india,455
```

File 2:

```
a,xyz,155
b,pqr,3215
c,lmn,3252
```

Expected combined file 3:

```
mike,sweden,2015
tom,USA,1522
raj,india,455
a,xyz,155
b,pqr,3215
c,lmn,3252
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Are there any additional constraints on how the files are being combined, e.g. sorting? Because if not, 'cat' and '>'/'>>' output redirection should do what you need.

Comment: Please [format your sample data properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I think Demon want to combine two files horizontal not vertically.

Comment: @Sung: Not according to the sample data (which is much more obvious now that the question has been properly formatted).

Comment: Indeed. Then the solution is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'd like to pass the file names as parameter to the script as i will want to eliminate the duplicate records if found in the combined file. – Demon 3 mins ago    edit   
     
Basically meaning after choosing say file 1 and file 2 to be combined, I'd like to pass the two names to a script along the name of the combined file (Name specified by me) while I try to de-duplicate the data in the combined file.

Comment: Please do not expand the scope of your question after answers have been given, because it invalidates existing answers. In this case, because both respondents updated their answer, please update your _question_ to reflect the full requirements. Generally, however, you should ask a _new_ question in this situation, and always state _all_ requirements _up front_.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to the original form of the question:**
As @Lars states in a comment on the question, it looks like a simple *concatenation* of the input files is desired, which is precisely what `cat` is for (and even *named* for):

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

**To fulfill the requirements you added later:**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Concatenate the input files and sort them with duplicates removed
# and save to output file.
cat "$1" "$2" | sort -u  > "$3"
```

Note, however, that you can combine the concatenation and sorting into a single step, as demonstrated by [Jean-Baptiste Yunès's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670604/45375):

```
# Sort the input files directly with duplicates removed and save to output file.
sort -u "$1" "$2" > "$3"
```

Note that **using `sort` is the simplest way to eliminate duplicates**.
**If you don't want sorting**, you'll have to use a different, more complex approach, e.g. with **`awk`**:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Process the combined input and only 
# output the first occurrence in a set of duplicates to the output file.
awk '!seen[$0]++' "$1" "$2" > "$3"
```

`!seen[$0]++` is a common `awk` idiom to only print the first in a set of duplicates:

- `seen` is an associative array that is filled with each input line (`$0`) as the key (index), with each element created on demand.
- This implies that all lines from a set of duplicates (even if not adjacent) refer to the *same* array element.
- In a numerical context, `awk`'s variable values and array elements are implicitly `0`, so when a given input line is seen for the *first time* and the post-decrement (`++`) is applied, the resulting value of the element is `1`.
- Whenever a duplicate of that line is later encountered, the value of the array element is incremented.
- The net effect is that for any given input line `!seen[$0]++` returns *true* if the input line is seen for the *first* time, and *false* for each of its duplicates, if any. Note that `++`, due to being a *post*-increment, is only applied *after* `!seen[$0]` is evaluated.

  - `!` *negates* the value of `seen[$0]`, causing a value of `0` - which is *false* in a Boolean context to return *true*, and any nonzero value (encountered for duplicates) to return *false*.
- `!seen[$0]++` is an instance of a so-called *pattern* in `awk` - a condition evaluated against the input line that determines whether the associated *action* (a block of code) should be processed. Here, there is no action, in which case `awk` implicitly simply *prints* the input line, if `!seen[$0]++` indicates *true*.
- The overall effect is: Lines are printed in input order, but for lines with duplicates only the first instance is printed, effectively eliminating duplicates.

Note that this approach can be problematic with large input files with few duplicates, because most of the data must then be held in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'd like to pass the file names as parameter to the script as i will want to eliminate the duplicate records if found in the combined file.

Comment: Basically meaning after choosing say file 1 and file 2 to be combined, I'd like to pass the two names to a script along the name of the combined file (Name specified by me) while I try to de-duplicate the data in the combined file.

Answer (score 1):

A script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sort "$1" "$2" | uniq > "$3"
```

should do the trick. Sort will sort the concatenation of the two files (two first args of the script), pass the result to `uniq` which will remove adjacent identical lines and push the result into the third file (third arg of the script).

Comment: ++ for showing  that `cat` is not needed (that you can pass multiple files directly to `sort`); consider using `sort -u` instead of involving `uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

If your file naming convention is same(say file1,file2,file3...fileN), then you can use this to combine all.

```
cat file* > combined_file
```

Edit: Script to do the same assuming you are passing file names as parameter

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $1 $2 $3 | uniq > combined_file
```

Now you can display combined_file if you want. Or access it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'd like to pass the file names as parameter to the script as i will want to eliminate the duplicate records if found in the combined file.
     
Basically meaning after choosing say file 1 and file 2 to be combined, I'd like to pass the two names to a script along the name of the combined file (Name specified by me) while I try to de-duplicate the data in the combined file.

Comment: `uniq` only eliminates adjacent identical lines, you need to sort first. Can the data be sorted?

Comment: Also, the parameter references should be double-quoted.